# recommended syntax for comments inside datalab %%sql module?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I had written a fairly complex %%sql module composed of 3 separate queries (the 3rd query calls the first two), and everything was working fine.  I went back to add descriptive comments in order to clarify what was being done (since this is material for a tutorial), and now my third query will not work because the comment lines are being wrapped together with subsequent non-comment lines -- more precisely, parts of the original sql are getting merged into the preceding comment line and thereby being removed from the sql.

Should I just completely avoid putting comments inside the %%sql module or is there a proper syntax that would allow this to work?  (or should gcp.bigquery.Query() intelligently strip out comments before passing sql on to BigQuery?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid comments. You could split the queries across multiple cells and use markdown cells in between.

We used to support comments starting with '#' in the first column but that has been removed.

Comment: Thank you Graham.  Since you suggest splitting the query across multiple cells, I thought it would be helpful to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590991/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-queries-defined-in-a-previous-sql-module-in-a-later) this previous question of mine.  I'd suggest an error message of some kind if a comment starting with '#' in the first column is encountered in a %%sql cell.

Answer (score 0):

One way of commenting inside the %%sql module is using '--' before the start of a comment.

```
%%sql --module query
-- Comment line 1
-- Comment line 2
SQL code
-- Comment line 3
```